# How can lambda functions and function typedefinitions work as a listener?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make the equivalent of a Event Listener from Java, but in C++.
My goal is, that I can call a function from a class, which triggers my listener I added to this class.

I found the following [Link](https://gist.github.com/4poc/3155832) which gave me a solution to do this.

The problem hereby is, that my program crashed as soon as I tried to call the listeners.

My code is structured like this:

```cpp
class MessageHandler abstract
{ 
public:
    typedef const std::function<void(int, std::string)> Handler;
    void addHandler(Handler& handler) {
            handlers.push_back(&handler);
    }
private:
    std::vector<Handler*> handlers;
protected:        
    void someFunction(int id, std::string message) {
        for (auto& handler : handlers) {
            (*handler)(id, message); //Here it will crash
        }
    }
};
```

As you maybe already mentioned, this is the base class from which I derive some childclasses. These childclasses call then my "someFunction" code.

And the class where I create one of these childclasses, is structured like this:

```cpp
class Server
{
private:
    SubHandler handler;

    void setHandlers() {
        handler.addHandler([&](int id, std::string message) { executingFunction(id, message); });
    }

    void executingFunction(int id, std::string message) {
        std::cout << "Listener Worked!" << std::endl;
        //Not actually the code inside, but it doesn't matter, case I don't even get to this code
    }
};
```

The program crashes at the line, where I loop over my listeners and call them with error:

> "Access violation when reading at position 0x000000000000000010."

(This is translated, so its not the message you will get if you have your Visual Studio set to English)

Comment: why do you store pointers ? I didnt read further, because most likely it is `std::vector<Handler*>` storing dangling pointers. Why not `std::vector<Handler>` ?

Comment: The lambda function is out of scope when you call it. And why do you store pointers to std::function, which it self is a pointer to function. You are storing pointers to pointers to functions.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mcve]. There are pieces of code missing (what is `SubHandler`?) 2) Does `handler.addHandler` call  end up in `MessageHandler::addHandler`? If so, you are storing a pointer of local variable. Which leads to a question of: Why `std::vector<Handler*> handlers;` instead of `std::vector<Handler> handlers;`?

Comment: Cause i copied that from the example you can see in the link above.

Comment: btw `abstract` is not a c++ keyword

Comment: @MaggieGrace "_Cause i copied that from the example you can see in the link above_" 1) All information, necessary to answer the question, must be in the question itself, and not hidden behind external links. 2) Be wary of [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: the example you copied from is pretty useless for anything else beyond that example ;). Be careful with capturing by reference and be careful with storing pointers

Comment: Okay, the example i use is doing it this way, of storing it as a pointer, to answer to the why pointer questions

Comment: @MaggieGrace I will repeat myself: 1) please provide [mcve], as without one, we can only guess at the problem. 2) Most likely you are storing pointer to a local variable (local lambda), which gets destroyed at the end of the function, before you call it.

Comment: Okay, i made two changes now.

The 1st is, that i kicked the pointer out of my vector and just stored them as you told me

The second change is, that i pulled out the code of my setHandler function into my message Loop, where i dont loose the scope of the Lambda function

Now its working. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe the code will be greatly simplified if you use `using xx =` or even templates or `std::function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compile your code using `/permissive-`. The compiler should refuse your code.

```
void addHandler(Handler& handler) {
        handlers.push_back(&handler);
}
```

You shouldn't be able to send a temporary to this function, but yet you are!

```
//                 v----- This lambda is a temporary object --------------------------v
handler.addHandler([&](int id, std::string message) { executingFunction(id, message); });
```

The lambda object created at that line dies just after the statement is finished.

```
//                 v---- pointer to the temporary.
handlers.push_back(&handler);
```

My recomendation would be to drop the pointer and use `std::function` object by value. They are made to be used like that:

```
//  abstract is not a C++ keyword.
class MessageHandler /* abstract */
{ 
public:
    // using instead of typedef and non const
    using Handler = std::function<void(int, std::string)>;

    void addHandler(Handler const& handler) { // const reference
            // insert by value
            handlers.push_back(handler);
    }
private:
    // no pointer here.
    std::vector<Handler> handlers;
protected:        
    void someFunction(int id, std::string message) {
        for (auto const& handler : handlers) {
            handler(id, message); //Here it will not crash anymore
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your lambda defined in your Server class method isn't in the scope of your MessageHandler class. I suggest you read through this : https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/03/demystifying-c-lambdas/ to get a good idea of what the problem is and how to fix it.

Though, it might be a good solution to define a struct holding your lambda, which would then work with [std::mem_fn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your source is bad :/
You might use instead something like:

```
class MessageHandler
{ 
public:
    using Handler = std::function<void(int, const std::string&)> Handler;

    void addHandler(const Handler& handler) { handlers.push_back(handler); }

    void execute(int id, const std::string& message) {
        for (auto& handler : handlers) {
            (*handler)(id, message);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Handler> handlers;
};
```

And then use it:

```
class Server
{
private:
    MessageHandler handler;

    void setHandlers()
    {
        handler.addHandler(&Server::executingFunction);
        handler.addHandler(
            [](int id, const std::string& message)
            {
                std::cout << message << id << std::endl;
            });
    }

    static void executingFunction(int id, const std::string& message) {
        std::cout << "Listener Worked!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```